# progress bar delegate fills vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtwidgets

I'm trying to paint a column in a `QTreeWidget` using a `QStylesItemDelegate` with a custom paint method, to give the appearance of a progress bar.

However, the progress bar is filling up from bottom to top, see attached screenshot (and also, the text is not showing!):
[image: screenshot]
Instead, I want it to fill up from left to right, and I believe this should have been set through the `QStyleOptionProgressBar.direction`?

Here is the MRE to produce my screenshot:

```
import sys

from PySide6 import (
    QtCore,
    QtWidgets
)


class MyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        progress_bar_option = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionProgressBar()
        progress_bar_option.rect = option.rect
        progress_bar_option.state = QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled
        progress_bar_option.direction = QtCore.Qt.LayoutDirection.LeftToRight
        progress_bar_option.fontMetrics = QtWidgets.QApplication.fontMetrics()

        progress_bar_option.minimum = 0
        progress_bar_option.maximum = 100
        progress_bar_option.textAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
        progress_bar_option.textVisible = True

        progress_bar_option.progress = 66
        progress_bar_option.text = 'demo'

        QtWidgets.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ProgressBar,
                                                progress_bar_option,  painter)


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.examplerow = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self)

        self.setHeaderLabels(['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'])
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        self.examplerow.setText(0, 'Content in first column')
        self.examplerow.setText(1, 'second')
        self.examplerow.setText(2, str(3))

        delegate = MyDelegate(self)

        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, delegate)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()

    widget = MyWidget()

    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(widget)
    window.resize(800, 600)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What is the correct way to change the direction of the progress bar?

Comment: Try adding the `QStyle.State_Horizontal` flag: `progress_bar_option.state = QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled | QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Horizontal`

Comment: Works like a charm. Would you convert your comment into an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `direction` variable has nothing to do with the progress bar *orientation*, since it's common for all QStyleOption classes and it's related to the *text layout direction* (left to right, or right to left for languages such as Hebrew or Arabic).

What you were looking for is the `orientation` variable, which has been considered obsolete since Qt 5.5 in favour of the appropriate `QStyle.State` flag:

```
# ...
progress_bar_option.state = QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled
progress_bar_option.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Horizontal
```